# Should I return something into a global variable or should I just set it? Whats the clean code way?

Tags: coding-style

I'm wondering if its best to use the following structure:

```
private var x = new MyType();
x = GetResults();
```

Or

```
public var x = new MyType();
GetResults();//this accesses the global x and populates it
```

Basically should I hide what I'm populating from the main thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's very obvious: The first one. Seems to be so obvoius that nobody has the balls to answer? The second solution just does not show what is going on.

Comment: Thankyou okay I just wanted some verification thanks, its hard when you code alone cos you can get stuck on basics!

Comment: And thinking about it too the methods can be less tightly coupled too if you use internal members in each method and return them at the end! Making refactoring easier!